# Copy a single file from main directory recursively across all directories within

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos, file-management

I'm on a dedicated server using CentOS, and on this server I have 5000+ directories in one main directory.

In the main directory I have an `index.php`. I would like to copy this `index.php` into all 5000+ directories, but the only way I know how is doing it manually.

Is there a way through the command line that I can enter something like `cp` and make it work from the directory? I'd copy it all the way down through all the directories and there sub directories within this main directory I am starting out in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec echo cp index.php {} \;
```

The above command would copy the `index.php` file from your current directory to all subdirectories, recursively – but not right away.

When you've made sure it prints all the correct copy commands, remove the `echo` and execute it. `echo` is just a safeguard to show you what the whole command would do before actually doing something you might not want.

Another interesting approach – thanks @RedGrittyBrick – would be to [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) the files instead of just plain copying them. This way, the `index.php` files in the subdirectories would all just be a shortcut, so to say, to the one in the root directory and not duplicated. To do this, in the above command, change `cp` to `ln -s`. This way, when you change the "master" `index.php` file, all the others in the subdirectories would still point to it and thus automatically change as well when viewed.

---

For completeness, the whole command, broken down, works like this:

- `find .`, search in the current directory
- `-mindepth 1`, going at least one directory deep
- `-type d`, only find directories
- `-exec …`, execute the command `echo cp index.php {}`, where `{}` is replaced with every directory found. This command is called multiple times, once for each subdirectory.

Comment: Before doing this, consider whether it might be better to use links (hard or soft) using `ln` rather than `cp`.